# How can I make the heading text of an eclipse editor selectable?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In an Eclipse Editor Part, you can add a text to the top bar of an editor form (see screenshot). How can I make this text selectable? And preferably copy-able via Ctrl+C or context menu?

The text is added via the `setText()` method of a `ScrolledForm` which in turn is generated by the editor's `FormToolkit`. I browsed the API but there seems nothing obvious to enable text selections.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment:  Details Explorer & Document Manager! Those were the days 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label` so it is not selectable text. I think you could add copy text Menu action on `FormHeading`.